# PDF of $\frac{X}{1+X^2}$ in terms of the PDF of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a r.v. $X$ with a know probability density $g$, I would like to find the probability density of $\frac{X}{1+X^2}$. Below I write my calculations:

denote

$f(X) := \frac{X}{1+X^2}$

Now $f$ is not monotone so we can't apply the known theorem, we proceed by finding the solutions to $\frac{X}{1+X^2} < c$ for the solutions to exist we need $-1/2<c < 1/2$ and the solutions to the associated quadratic equation will be $x_{1-2} = 1 \pm\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c)$.

I obtain that 
$$P(f(X) < c) = P( \{X <1 -\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c)\} \cup \{ X > 1 +\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c)  \}) = 1-P(X < 1 +\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c)) + P(X <1 -\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c))$$

So the resulting density of $\frac{X}{1+X^2}$ will be $$1+ \frac{ 4c/ \sqrt{1-4c^2} + 2(1+\sqrt{1-4c^2})}{4c^2}g(1 +\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c)) + \frac{ 4c/ \sqrt{1-4c^2} - 2(1-\sqrt{1-4c^2})}{4c^2}g(1 -\sqrt{1-4c^2}/ (2c)$$
with the condition that $-1/2<c<1/2$.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the CDF**

Let
$$
G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
be the CDF of $X$ and $Y=\frac{X}{X^2+1}$. Then the CDF of $Y$ is
$$
\begin{align}
F(\lambda)
&=P(y\lt\lambda)\\
&=P\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\lt\lambda\right)\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
P\left(x\lt\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}\right)-P\left(x\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}\right)+1&\text{if $0\le\lambda\lt\frac12$}\\
P\left(x\lt\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}\right)-P\left(x\lt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}\right)&\text{if $-\frac12\le\lambda\lt0$}
\end{array}\right.\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
G\left(\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}\right)-G\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}\right)+1&\text{if $0\lt\lambda\le\frac12$}\\
G(0)&\text{if $\lambda=0$}\\
G\left(\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}\right)-G\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}\right)&\text{if $-\frac12\le\lambda\lt0$}
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
f(\lambda)
&=F'(\lambda)\\[9pt]
&=\tfrac2{1-4\lambda^2+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}g\left(\tfrac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}\right)+\tfrac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda^2\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}g\left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Using Only the PDF**

Suppose that $Y=g(X)$ and $f_X(x)$ is the PDF for $X$. Consider the case of an infinitesimal interval, $\mathrm{d}x$, in $X$ and the corresponding infinitesimal interval, $\mathrm{d}y$, in $Y$:

[image]

When $g'(x)\gt0$, The probability of an event occurring in $\mathrm{d}x$ is $f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{f_X(x)}{g'(x)}\,\mathrm{d}y$.

When $g'(x)\lt0$, The probability of an event occurring in $\mathrm{d}x$ is $f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{f_X(x)}{g'(x)}\,\mathrm{d}y$.

Thus, the probability of an event occurring in $\mathrm{d}x$ is $f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{f_X(x)}{|g'(x)|}\,\mathrm{d}y$.

The probability of and event occurring in $\mathrm{d}y$ is the sum of the probabilities over all the points $x_k$ where $g(x_k)=y$. That is,
$$
f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=\sum_{g(x_k)=y}\frac{f_X(x_k)}{|g'(x_k)|}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{4}
$$
Thus, the PDF of $Y$ is
$$
f_Y(y)=\sum_{g(x_k)=y}\frac{f_X(x_k)}{|g'(x_k)|}\tag{5}
$$
Which is the formula cited in Did's answer.

Comment: As already explained, to deduce a PDF from another PDF, the détour PDF $\to$ CDF $\to$ CDF $\to$ PDF is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but how do you get  $x< \frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}$ in your first method?

Comment: @Monolite: that comes from finding $x$ so that $\frac{x}{x^2+1}\lt\lambda$. If $\lambda\gt0$, we want $x\lt\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}$ or $x\gt\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}$. If $\lambda\lt0$, we want $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}\lt x\lt\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}$.

Comment: @Monolite: yes, but $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}=\frac{2\lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}$ and the latter behaves better for small $\lambda$.

Comment: I have a doubt: although the CDF has a jump at zero it is still continuous because  it is not defined at zero and this justifies the fact that we obtain that $Y$ is an absolutely continuous random variable?

Comment: @Monolite: The limit from both sides is $G(0)$. I didn't put that point in, but that doesn't mean the CDF has a jump. I will add that to the definition.

Comment: Sorry to keep on bothering, I tried to prove that the resulting CDF is differentiable for $\lambda = 0$ utilizing the definition of derivative and de l'hopital but to no avail, is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: Using the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) you should be able to show that if the limit of the derivative at $\lambda=0$ exists and the function is continuous at $\lambda=0$, then the derivative at $\lambda=0$ is equal to the limit of the derivative at $\lambda=0$.

Comment: But doesn't the limit of the derivative at $\lambda = 0$ blow up?

Comment: I have arrived at a point where the derivative exists only for certain degrees of freedom of the student-t, is there any hope this is correct?

Comment: When $g(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$, $g'(0)=1$, so $f_Y(0)=f_X(0)$.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested to know that, if $X$ has PDF $f_X$ and if $Y=h(X)$ for some function $h$ regular enough then, [the PDF $f_Y$ of $Y$ is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)

> $$f_Y(y)=\sum_{x:h(x)=y}\frac1{|h'(x)|}f_X(x)$$

In your case, $$h(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ hence $f_Y(y)=0$ for $|y|\geqslant\frac12$. For every $0<|y|<\frac12$, $h(x)=y$ if and only if $x=\xi_\pm(y)$, where $$\xi_\pm(y)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$ Furthermore, $$h'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$$ hence $$h'(\xi_\pm(y))=\mp\frac{y\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{\xi_\pm(y)}$$ which yields, for every $0<|y|<\frac12$,
$$f_Y(y)=\sum_{\pm}\frac{\xi_\pm(y)}{y\sqrt{1-4y^2}}f_X(\xi_\pm(y))$$
The actual computational details in the specific case that interests you may be slightly involved but (I hope it is apparent that) the method itself is straightforward, even when, as here, $h$ is not injective.

Comment: (+1) good generalization, and I have added a section to my answer justifying this formula. However, as this was posted after my initial answer, the "already explained" comment is puzzling.

Comment: @robjohn Not puzzling at all, I posted several similar remarks in the past explaining exactly this and I remember that you saw at least one of them. (But why not react to a comment about your answer  by posting a comment to your answer?)

Comment: Where could I find out how regular must the function $h$ be?

Comment: @Monolite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution